# Захватить нажатие пробелa на мобильном устройстве JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on("keyup", 'input[name=create--post--tag-more]', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    console.info('Вы нажали пробел');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="create--post--tag-more" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

На компьютере я могу поймать нажатие на `пробел` кодом выше, а как поймать его на мобильных устройствах?

Comment: Попробуйте 229 =) Подробнее про этот [баг](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639)

Comment: 229 вообще реагирует на любую клавишу

Comment: Почитайте подробнее про этот баг, думаю там помогут.

Comment: @And а причем тут баг 2012 года, который еще и закрыт?

Comment: @ThisMan, ну как видите, у человека не работает, иначе бы вопрос отвалился бы сам собой.